# EditText changes background color after focus

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` inside `CardView` which changes its background color after gaining focus, like writing text in it. I want it to be like the second picture.

**Before focus:**

[image: Before focus]

**After focus:**

[image: After focus]

**Code:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:hint="@string/search_library"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Set edit text background as android:background="@null"

Comment: @ADM Doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using focusable properties in card view ? remove these attributes and foreground too .

Comment: Try removing the foreground attr.

Comment: @ADM Removing foreground worked. I was using it to get a ripple feedback on the CardView, but with EditText that was of no use. Thanks!

Comment: @fightingCoder Thanks. That worked.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat pls upvote the answer if u wouldnt mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the foreground attr.

Answer (score 1):

Use `selector` for changing back ground when edittext focused.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_notfocused" />
</selector>
```

then add your preferences in `edittext_focused.xml` file.